# OpenCV and Python installation

Tags: python, opencv

I have downloaded OpenCV 2.4.10 and followed the steps on http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html#linux-installation.

I am missing the next steps...

What do I need to do to be able to import cv2? (I get ImportError)

Comment: I am not sure but may be you can use pre-compiled binaries? (python-opencv on ubuntu) Sorry for my English

Comment: did you run a `make install` ? that should copy your cv2.pyd to pyton/lib/site-packages

Comment: I have also always found [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenCV) link to be of most help. That script works for me every time. Check out the flags set for `cmake` for hints. There's also aditional bash scripts at the bottom for gcc and g++

Comment: as @Dark_Daiver said, you'd be better served with a simple `sudo apt-get install python-opencv` than trying to build everything by yourself

Comment: you rock @goncalopp. I wasted too mich time trying to install to pip install pyopencv, sudo apt-get opencv-dev and installing wrappers that I didn't manage to make work. Thanks a lot!